# Loading JSON in D3 gives null value

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm using D3 to render a map of the United States. When I try to load the JSON file, however, I get this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'features' of null

This is the JSON file I'm using: https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_12/us-states.json

It's located in the same directory as all of my other files.

```
// determine width and height
var w = 500;
var h = 300;

// define map projection
var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa();

// this translates geojson coordinates to svg path codes
var path = d3.geoPath()
             .projection(projection);

// create svg
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

// load in the geojson file
d3.json("states.json", function(json) {
        console.log(json); // <---- comes up as "null"
        // create one path per geojson feature
        svg.selectAll("path")
           .data(json.features) // <---- THIS is where the error is apparently coming from
           .enter()
           .append("path")
           .attr("d", path);
});
```

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what most of this means, but it looks like it's going through correctly? Status: 304 - Type: xhr - Initiator: d3.v4.min.js - Size: 136 B - Time: 7ms. When I select states.json from the Network tab, the preview tab seems to be showing the JSON correctly. All three of the files I'm using -- index.html, states.json, and render-map.js -- are in the same directory. Trying an absolute path didn't change anything.

Comment: It looks like your JSON file contains invalid characters, ie multibyte characters. If you use the correct callback definition and log the error argument you get an error message about it trying to parse the JSON file. How did you save the JSON file from github? Copy/Paste or direct download? You may have to redownload it

Comment: I did a copy/paste from the github Raw code into Notepad++. Re-tried it with direct download and am no longer getting the error! That seems to have been the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument in the anonymous function is 'error'. It's like

```
d3.json(filePath, function(err,data){
if(err) console.log("error fetching data");
// data holds the file content
});
```

Probably u missed that. Check https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm no longer getting the error message (see comments above). I'm a bit confused by the error argument. The tutorial I'm following doesn't use that: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch12.html#_paths -- Is that something new with D3 v4?

Comment: @BenjaminSchroeder, it's an optional argument.  If the callback is passed one argument it's data, two it's error,data

Comment: `error` is an optional argument. `d3.json` works just fine with 1 argument only.